# Amount of items on the same level of hierarchy

Tags: java, jpa, hierarchical-data

I have a table:

```
id|name|parent
--------------
1 |test|null
2 |tt1 |1
3 |tt2 |1
4 |tt3 |1
5 |tt4 |2
6 |tt5 |3
7 |tt6 |2
```

which looks like this tree:

```
     test
   /   |   \
  tt1 tt2 tt3
  / \       \
tt4 tt6     tt5
```

The question is how to find amount of the nodes on the same level as a given node. For ex.: for `tt2` the answer is `3` and for `tt5` the answer is `3` as well. But I am out of idea, how to do it? Even not speaking about the most optimized and correct way.

I have created a java Entity with corresponding mapping to the same column in the table and implemented a getter that returns the path to the root, so that I can find out the level. Also, I have imlemented a method that finds amount of the siblings for the given node. Created these getters, since I thought it will help me.

Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "hierarchy")

public class Hierarchy implements Serializable {

    private Integer idNode;
    private String name;
    private Hierarchy parentNode;
    private Set<Hierarchy> children;

    public Hierarchy() {
    }

    public Hierarchy(Integer idNode, String name) {
        this.idNode = idNode;
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getIdNode() {
        return idNode;
    }

    public void setIdNode(Integer idNode) {
        this.idNode = idNode;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", length = 500)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    public Hierarchy getParentNode() {
        return parentNode;
    }

    public void setParentNode(Hierarchy parentNode) {
        this.parentNode = parentNode;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentNode")
    public Set<Hierarchy> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Hierarchy> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hierarchy [idNode=" + idNode + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

    @Transient
    public int getSiblingsNum() {
        if (this.getParentKeyword() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return this.getParentNode().getChildren().size() - 1;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<Hierarchy> getPath() {
        Hierarchy name = this;
        List<Hierarchy> path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(name);
        while (name.getParentNode() != null) {
            name = name.getParentNode();
            path.add(name);
        }
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((idNode == null) ? 0 : idNode.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Hierarchy other = (Hierarchy) obj;
        if (idNode == null) {
            if (other.idNode != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!idNode.equals(other.idNode))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to redesign the database schema for such a problem. You can look at the book SQL Antipatterns by Bill Karwin chapter Naive Trees.

If that's not an option you have to navigate till the root to find the level of your element and then recursively iterate till the found level and count all the elements.

Something like this:

```
public int getSameLevelNum() {
    int level = 0;
    Hierarchy current = this;
    while(current.getParentNode() != null){
        level++;
        current = current.getParentNode();
    }
    return recurse(current, level);
}

int recurse(Hierarchy node, int level){
    if(level == 0) return node.children.size();
    level--;
    int r = 0;
    for(Hierarchy child : node.children)
            r+= recurse(child, level);  

    return r;
}
```

Comment: The solution with going up to the root was pretty clear. I thought maybe it's possible to go some other way. Because the tree is quite big and calculation of that everytime takes quite of time. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.